# Jquery Ajax Web page scraping using c#

Tags: c#, ajax, web-scraping

I try to scrap a webpage using c#.net 3.5 application but i am not able to scrap full page because some content showing via jquery Ajax.

[see this](http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/result_home.sd#resultDay=2012-12-16&meetingId=18&isFullMeeting=true)

and here are my codes

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/result_home.sd#resultDay=2012-12-16&meetingId=18&isFullMeeting=true";

        WebClient w = new WebClient();
        string s = w.DownloadString(url);


    }
```

i need the race result from the website which is show by Ajax i think.

Comment: I have found the problem alternative but not ans of my question. I am using the ajax url directly http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/result_by_meeting_full.sd?r_date=2012-12-12&meeting_id=18 so its solved for me but can we do with ajax url ??

Comment: Can you explain the question in your last comment more? (What do you mean by "what can we do with ajax url?")

Answer (score 1):

http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/result_by_meeting_full.sd?r_date=2012-12-16&meeting_id=18

If you use Chrome for your web browser, you can open up developer tools (F12) and look in the "Network" tab to see what resources are requested after the page loads.  The above URL is one of the ones I noticed seems to pull some results. If you know or can parse date and meeting_id you could probably make calls directly as you are with the main page.

Another possible option is using an actual [web browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) and scanning the DOM after everything has finished loading.

Comment: yes its help already did and find the solution but can we do without doing like this. only with c# code?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to work with `System.Net` namespace.
What you need to do is create `HttpRequest` with the help like this

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/result_home.sd#resultDay=2012-12-16&meetingId=18&isFullMeeting=true");
WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

I guess this would give complete response with Ajax data as well.