# Can't download webpage via C# webclient and via request/respond

Tags: c#, http, webclient

I want to download webpages html code, but have problems with several links. For example: http://www.business-top.info/, http://azerizv.az/
I recieve no html at all using this:
1. WebClient:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                string result = client.DownloadString(resultUrl);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

2. Http request/response

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resultUrl);
            request.Method = "POST";
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

There are many such links, so I can't download html manually just via sourse code of web page via browser

Comment: Concerning your second example: can you try to use the `GET`-Method?

Comment: Get method returns nothing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pages load in stages. First they load the core of the page and only then they evaluate any JavaScript inside which loads further content via AJAX. To scrape these pages you will need more advanced content scraping libraries, than just simple HTTP request sender.

EDIT:
Here is a question in SO about the same problem that you are having now:
[Jquery Ajax Web page scraping using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028934/jquery-ajax-web-page-scraping-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you please advice some libraries for that? And does webclient also not provide such fucntions?