# Why can't Golang download certain webpages?

Tags: go, html, go-http

I want to download Fantasy Football Data to analyse in Go, but when I try to download from [this api page](https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static) then I get back an empty response, even though the code works for other websites, e.g. [this api page](https://api.tfl.gov.uk/StopPoint/Meta/Categories)

Minimal reproduction, outputs an empty array.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

const AllPlayerData = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static"

func main() {
    downloadAllData()
}

func downloadAllData() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: 20 * time.Second,
    }

    response, err := client.Get(AllPlayerData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to download player data.")
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to read response")
        return
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println(body)
}
```

The same webpage downloads fine in Python:

```
import requests
url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.content)
```

I don't think it's related to e.g. [Ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989139/cant-download-webpage-via-c-sharp-webclient-and-via-request-respond) as viewing the network requests in Chrome doesn't show up any beyond the page load itself

Comment: Did you try logging the error message? `fmt.Println("error: %v", err)`
If there's no error, just an empty response, did you check the response headers? Maybe it's a redirect that python automatically follows, but the Go client doesn't.

Comment: There weren't any error messages, nor any useful response headers. The response had a status of 200, but Content length 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are doing some sort of validation on the user agent, the following code works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

const AllPlayerData = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static"

func main() {
    downloadAllData()
}

func downloadAllData() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: 20 * time.Second,
    }

    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, AllPlayerData, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to create request.")
        return
    }
    request.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36")
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to download player data.")
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to read response")
        return
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks a lot Dave! I assume python applies headers by default, but do you know if that's also true of Postman?

Comment: Go actually has a user agent by default too, `const defaultUserAgent = "Go-http-client/1.1"`, I'd imagine PostMan either has one or uses your browsers.  It's hard to know *why* Go's default was blocked, but it's just a common issue with scraping - in general you want to emulate a real browser as much as possible

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Looks like they're checking for `Mozilla`. I sent a request with _only_ `Mozilla` as the user agent, and they sent the data.